# phpmyadmin cant select data from tables

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Then I went to phpmyadmin and found this:

```
#1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_table_uiprefs'
```

How do I get rid of that error? is it something with permissions..please help

I tried this..didnt work:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Here is in codeIgniter:

```
> $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
```

I tried to change the password in my.ini
:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';

didnt work
```

Comment: Yes its about Permissions only... Check the username and password given and also the permissions for that user..

Comment: see update..I cant get to the database through the admin, but not through the phpmyadmin... the username is root. lol..downvote already

Comment: Not sure...but try this...edit your password in `config.inc` in `wamp\apps\phpmyadmin`

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you are mixing a couple of things:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

here above the user is *user* while in your codeIgniter(CI) coed it is `$db['default']['username'] = 'root';` user *root*

Even if you want to keep the same CI code then you need to specify password for user *root* which currently you are giving blank `$db['default']['password'] = '';`

Comment: i went to config.inc.. and deleted some $cfg variable... all the codeigniter code is set..

Comment: Thanks the problem wasnt in the password but in this .$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';.. the port was 82 instead of 80.. so I changed it to just hte ip number and now it works